# converting ppt to html

Tags: java, spring, html, powerpoint

I want to implement a function that can see PowerPoint on the web at this time.
You can do it simply by converting PowerPoint to an image, but if you convert it to an image, I think there are issues that you can not use video or audio.

So the idea was to convert PowerPoint to HTML and place it where I wanted. However, it does not have much ability to directly implement the pure function of converting PowerPoint to HTML. To solve this problem, I have been looking for open source or various libraries, but I have not found them yet.

The development environment is java8 + Spring Boot.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. Your feedback has really helped me. Once you've found a solution, we'll share it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with converting your PPT files to PDF before converting them to HTML, then [pdf2htmlEX](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX) could be worth looking at. It is the best tool I could find for this kind of work, as it is capable of converting PDFs to HTML very precisely (have a look at the exmples [1](http://coolwanglu.github.io/pdf2htmlEX/demo/issue65_en.html),[2](http://coolwanglu.github.io/pdf2htmlEX/demo/geneve.html),[3](http://coolwanglu.github.io/pdf2htmlEX/demo/cheat.html),[4](http://coolwanglu.github.io/pdf2htmlEX/demo/demo.html)). You should be able to find wrapper libraries in the maven repo so that you are able to call it from your Java applications.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK in using iframe you may use a Microsoft solution  https://products.office.com/it-IT/office-online/view-office-documents-online

You may use this code:

```
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=[you_ppt_url]' width='100%' height='600px' frameborder='0'>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution looks good but it does not work anymore. It displays this french (error) message :
Une erreur s’est produite. Désolé. Nous ne parvenons pas à l’ouvrir. En savoir plus

Answer (score 0):

There's an older node package called [PPTX2HTML](https://github.com/g21589/PPTX2HTML). It outputs a bunch of garbled code on a canvas element, but it might work. They even have a demo website to try it out. They seemed to have broken the powerpoint up into parseable XML and rendered the elements.